# On connecting to nvidia port and enabling nvidia graphics card, no display coming on monitor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04, weston

The device has both intel and nvidia graphics card and by using prime-select i have selected for nvidia graphics card.
Still no display is coming on monitor. Weston too has been disbaled which should atleast display the terminal on monitor but even that isn't coming.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.